# Building from substrings using a Suffix Trie

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, trie, suffix

I have an exam upcoming and I am trying to revise. I came across this question and I am stuck as to how do I proceed. The question is as follows:

Given the function build_from_substrings(S,T), if you are able to build T from the substrings of S, the function should return a tuple containing the first and last indexes of the substrings used to build T. For example "bcc" is created from the indexes of (2,4) from "abbcc". If the substring cannot be created then the function returns false.

build_from_substrings must run in O(N^2 + M) where:

1. N is the number of characters in S
2. M is the length of T

I have successfully created a suffix trie to store the suffixes of S. However, I am failing to grasp the second part of the question, the traversal and substring search. Can I please get some guidance?

This is what I have tried.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,level = None,size = 27,data = None):
        self.link = [None] * size
        self.level = level
        self.data = data
        self.end = False

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def insert(self,key,data):
        level = 0
        current = self.root
        for char in key:
            index = ord(char) - 97 + 1
            if current.link[index] is not None:
                current = current.link[index]
            else:
                current.link[index] = Node(level=level)
                current = current.link[index]
            level += 1
        index = 0
        if current.link[index] is not None:
            current = current.link[index]
        else:
            current.link[index] = Node(level=level)
            current = current.link[index]
        current.data = data

    def search(self,key):
        current = self.root
        for char in key:
            index = ord(char) - 97 + 1
            if current.link[index] is not None:
                current = current.link[index]
            else:
                return False
        index = 0
        if current.link[index] is not None:
            current = current.link[index]
            return current.data
        else:
            return False

def build_from_substring(S,T):
    suffix_trie = Trie()
    length = len(S)
    for i in range(len(S)):
        list = [i,0]
        word = ""
        word += S[i]
        if i == length-1:
            list[1] = i
        for j in range(i+1,length):
            word += S[j]
            list[1] = length-1
        suffix_trie.insert(word,list)
```

Comment: Which part of the traversal are you stuck on how? "What" to do or "how" to do?

Comment: If you construct it out of multiple substrings you return a list of multiple tuples containing the first and last index of each substring? The stated instruction return a tuple implies just one.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your question but I hope this helps. I started by re-writing your entire class for a Trie, I thought this might be more useful.

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}
        self.end = '*'

    def insert(self,word):
        '''Traverses the string and inserts each character into the Trie'''
        current = self.root
        for char in word:
            if char not in current:
                current[char] = {}
            current = current[char]
        current[self.end] = self.end

    def search(self,word):
        '''Returns True if word is in the Trie and False if the word is not in the Trie. The search word must not be a substring in the Trie.'''
        current = self.root
        for char in word:
            if char not in current:
                return False
            current = current[char]
        return True if self.end in current else False
```

Then established some cases of when to return a pair of indices and when to return False.

```
trie = Trie()
trie.insert('word')
build_from_substrings('have you heard the word in the worlds.', trie)
(19, 22)
build_from_substrings('have these words today.', trie)
(11, 14)
build_from_substrings('have you heard.', trie)
False
```

Traverse the input string and if there is a match in the Trie mark down the index. If they match until the word in the Trie is completed markdown the end index and return. If they do not match while traversing the string return False.

```
def build_from_substrings(string,trie):
    current = trie.root
    start = None
    end = None
    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        if char in current:
            if start is None:
            '''recored the starting index where they first match'''
                start = idx
            current = current[char]
        elif start and trie.end in current:
        '''If start is not none and our Trie has an end symbol we have reached a word'''
            return (start,idx-1)
        else:
        '''if the character(char) is not in current then we need to start over by resetting "current" value and "start" value'''
            current = trie.root
            start = None
    if start is None or trie.end not in current:
    '''If our start value is None or there is no end symbol then that means we have no substrings to report'''
        return False
    return (start,end) if end else (start,len(string)-1)
```